VBA running to extract tables from Master Word Document and populating other word documents in other folders
I am running this code and I have tried everything to get it to extract the tables from the master word document to populate downstream project documentation. Currently when the code runs it creates the word document I need, in the correct folder(s) at the correct configuration number. The problem is it is only copying the section headers from the master and not the tables under those headers. I have tried book marking, book marking at the start and end of the section but nothing has worked thus far.I am trying to work on one section of the master at the moment but eventually will want to do the same thing for risks, timelines etc.
Sub ExtractRiskManagementSections()
    Dim wdDoc As Document
    Dim newDoc As Document
    Dim folderPaths As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim headerText As String
    Dim sectionStart As Range
    Dim sectionEnd As Range
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim projectNumber As String
    Dim versionNumber As Integer
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim copySection As Boolean
    Dim contentRange As Range
    
    ' Define the file path
    filePath = "C:\\test\\Program 1-PID-TEST.docx"
    
    ' Check if the file exists
    If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File found: " & filePath
        ' Open the master document
        Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(filePath)
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found: " & filePath
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Define folder paths for each project
    folderPaths = Array( _
        "C:\\Users\\james\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Organisation Strategy\\Programs\\Program 1\\P1-Projects\\P1-Project 1\\1. Project 1 Controls\\", _
        "C:\\Users\\james\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Organisation Strategy\\Programs\\Program 1\\P1-Projects\\P1-Project 2\\1. Project 2 Controls\\", _
        "C:\\Users\\james\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Organisation Strategy\\Programs\\Program 1\\P1-Projects\\P1-Project 3\\1. Project 3 Controls\\")
    
    ' Loop through each project folder
    For i = 0 To UBound(folderPaths)
        ' Create a new document for each project
        Set newDoc = Documents.Add
        projectNumber = "Project " & (i + 1)
        
        ' Loop through each paragraph in the document to find headers
        For Each para In wdDoc.Paragraphs
            headerText = para.Range.Text
            copySection = False
            
            ' Check if the header contains the project number and "Risk"
            If InStr(headerText, projectNumber) > 0 And InStr(headerText, "Risk") > 0 Then
                copySection = True
                Set sectionStart = para.Range
                sectionStart.End = wdDoc.Content.End
                
                ' Find the end of the section
                For Each innerPara In wdDoc.Paragraphs
                    If innerPara.Range.Start > sectionStart.Start Then
                        If InStr(innerPara.Range.Text, "Project") > 0 Or InStr(innerPara.Range.Text, "Scope") > 0 Or InStr(innerPara.Range.Text, "Timelines") > 0 Then
                            Set sectionEnd = innerPara.Range
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next innerPara
                
                If Not sectionEnd Is Nothing Then
                    sectionStart.End = sectionEnd.Start
                End If
                
                ' Copy the section including tables
                Set contentRange = wdDoc.Range(sectionStart.Start, sectionStart.End)
                contentRange.Copy
                newDoc.Content.Paste
                newDoc.Content.InsertAfter vbCrLf ' Add a line break between sections
                MsgBox "Copied section: " & headerText ' Debugging message
                
                Exit For ' Exit after copying the relevant section
            End If
        Next para
        
        ' Determine the version number
        versionNumber = 1
        Do While Dir(folderPaths(i) & projectNumber & " Documentation " & Format(versionNumber, "00") & ".docx") <> ""
            versionNumber = versionNumber + 1
        Loop
        
        ' Save the new document in the corresponding folder with the correct name and version number
        newFileName = folderPaths(i) & projectNumber & " Documentation " & Format(versionNumber, "00") & ".docx"
        newDoc.SaveAs2 newFileName
        newDoc.Close
    Next i
End Sub

Thanks in advance
Documented in my previous statement

Why are you using double backslashes instead of a single backslash in file paths?

It would be far more efficient to either loop through the tables (e.g. For each Tbl in wdDoc.Tables), then check for whether the 'Risk' or 'Project' header is there, or use Word's wildcard Find function to locate the 'Risk' & 'Project' headers (Find = [PR][ir][os][jk]), than looping through every paragraph. Your current code, for example, quite unnecessarily loops through every paragraph in every table. Also, Copy/Paste is much less efficient than using .FormattedText. Check it out.

Just a note that the term "Master Document" refers to a Word "feature" that often causes problems. https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart

If your document contains tables that are not appearing in the output, it's almost certainly because you are not expanding the subdocuments before processing the master document. If you don't expand, all the VBA "sees" is the content in the Master Document and not the Subdocuments. So e.g. you could start by changing this
   Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(filePath)

to this
   Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(filePath)
   wdDoc.Subdocuments.Expanded = True

I am not familiar with processing Master Documents, but I think you will also need to wait for the expansion to finish. It may be enough to change that code to the following:
   Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(filePath)
   wdDoc.Subdocuments.Expanded = True
   wdDoc.Repaginate

but I haven't tested that thoroughly.

I believe the OP is misusing the term "Master Document", just as they are also misusing the term "header".

It could also be the case that the headings are collapsed in the target documents.
